# CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING between two Pipes

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, substring

I have a string in a table :

S-1-5-21-109290937-1013972632-435976164-15678|l.smith|DOMAIN-UK|0x95231|1

I need to extract the data between the first and second | .

So from the above it would return l.smith only.
I have tried various `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRINGS` but it always errors, the length of the string also changes so I cant trim the other | out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this just now, Hope this is what you are looking for,

```
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(MAX) = 'S-1-5-21-109290937-1013972632-435976164-15678|l.smith|DOMAIN-UK|0x95231|1';
DECLARE @FIRSTINDEX INT = CHARINDEX('|',@VALUE,1);
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(@VALUE, @FIRSTINDEX+1, CHARINDEX('|',@VALUE,@FIRSTINDEX+1)-CHARINDEX('|',@VALUE,1)-1);
```

Comment: If this works on the 1st pipe how do I get this to work on the next pipe and so on?